# Stopping other code from displaying with noscript?

Tags: javascript

I want to block people using my site without JavaScript as it will just cause problems as most of my website is coded in JavaScript, and relies on it for validation, ajax, and lots more.

I've learnt by adding `<noscript>` you can display a message to those who don't have javascript enabled, is there a way to stop it displaying the rest of the page, and only the noscript? Otherwhys it doesn't really have any use...

Comment: If you generate the page with JavaScript then people with JS disabled won't see it.

Comment: I don't generate it with JavaScript, its just functionality relies on JavaScript, which would be seen as "not working" to a visitor, and they wouldn't know why.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. I was suggesting that you *start* generating the HTML with JS to solve it. Another option is to set the content's CSS to `display: none` and re-show it with JS.

Comment: You know, you could just try to make your site [accessible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility)…

Comment: Are there on 2018 browsers with no js support? Or users disabling javascript (well, they sure won't see a lot of websites functionning nice with js disabled) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a banner of varying size with a high [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), like this:

```
<noscript style="position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;height:20vh;
                 background:#fff;z-index:100000">
Please <a href="https://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
enable JavaScript</a>.
</noscript>
```

Adapt the wording and design to the style of your website.

If your website is really completely unusable without JavaScript, set height to 100vh (or `bottom:0`) to cover the whole screen.